# Probability question, statistics and actuarial science.

Tags: probability

A car dealership sells 0, 1, or 2 luxury cars on any day. When selling a car, the dealer also tries to persuade the customer to buy an extended warranty for the car. Let X denote the number of luxury cars sold in a given day, and let Y denote the number of extended warranties sold.

P(X = 0, Y = 0) = 1 / 6

P(X = 1, Y = 0) = 1/12

P(X = 1, Y = 1) = 1 /6

P(X = 2, Y = 0) = 1 /12

P(X = 2, Y = 1) = 1 /3

P(X = 2, Y = 2) = 1/6

What is the variance of X?

Answer (score 0):

It is

$P(X=x_i)=\begin{cases}\sum_{j=0}^2 P(X=x_i,Y=y_i) \ \text{for} \ x_i=0,1,2 \\ \\ 0, \text{elsewhere} \end{cases}$

And $E(X)=\mu _x=\sum_{0}^2 x_i \cdot P(X=x_i)$

$Var(X)=\sum_{i=0}^2 (x_i-\mu_x )^2 \cdot P(X=x_i)$